# javascript code that only works outside of a function - why?

Tags: javascript, function

How come this code does not work as its written below but if I comment out `function testBgChange(){` and keep the code inside that function it works fine. What difference does it make if I keep the code within the function and then call that function?

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    testBgChange();
    function testBgChange(){
        var i = 0;
        var c = 0;
        var time = 3000;
        var incr = 3000;

        while(i<=3){
            if(c==0){
                var red = "#FF0000";
                setTimeout("changeBgColor(red)",time);
                time+=incr;
                c=1;
            }
            else if(c==1){
                var white = "#FFFFFF";
                setTimeout("changeBgColor(white)",time);
                time+=incr;
                c=0;
            }
        i+=1;
        }
    }

    function changeBgColor(color){
        document.getElementById("alert").style.backgroundColor = color;
    }


</script>

</head>
<body>
<p id="alert">
    <br>
    <br>
    Testing
    <br>
    <br>
</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `var red` and `var white`, when declared inside the function, can only be accessed from within the function. This is a problem because`setTimeout` will call `eval` in the global scope, which does not have access to these variables.

There are a variety of ways to work around this, but it's better practice to give `setTimeout` a function rather than a string. This will solve your problem as the new function creates a *closure* that retains access to the variables in the containing function:

```
var red = "#FF00000";
setTimeout(function () {
    changeBgColor(red);
}, time);
```

Comment: Thanks! Wouldnt have figured that out =)