# jQuery doesn't work in <head>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is supposed to make a slideshow out of stacked list-elements (I commented out the CSS so I can see what's going on) by fading out the topmost elements until only the first one is visible, then fade in the topmost element and the rest and start anew. If I put the script below my content inside the `<body>` and throw out the `$(function() {` it works perfectly fine, but in the `<head>` nothing happens. I wrote this yesterday and today I still can't see the mistake, so I'm posting it here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        ul {
            position: relative;
        }
        ul li {
            /*position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;*/
        }
    </style>
    <script src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var i = 0;
            var count = $('ul li').size();      

            function fade() {
                if (i < count-1) {
                $('ul li:nth-child('+(count-i)+')').fadeOut(300);
                    i++;
                } else {
                    $('ul li:nth-child('+count+')').fadeIn(300, function(){$('ul li').show();});    
                    i = 0;
                }
            }

            $('button').click(function() {
                setInterval('fade()', 1000);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button>Slideshow GO!</button>
    <ul id="slider">
        <li><img src="1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="2.jpg" /></li>    
        <li><img src="3.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="4.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that wrapping your code inside `$(function () {})` causes the `fade` function to be declared **locally**, and not **globally**. `setTimeout` evaluates `'fade()'` in the global scope, so it can't find the function.

It's generally bad practice to give `setTimeout` a string anyway, so replace it with a pointer to the function:

```
setTimeout(fade, 1000);
```

I answered a similar question not long ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139999/javascript-code-that-only-works-outside-of-a-function-why/5140026#5140026), but that question also relies on access to local variables from within the setTimeout.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works. I had tried `setTimeout(fade(), 1000);`, without the quotes, but that didn't do anything. Now without the parentheses it works, although I don't really see why.

Comment: @Hanz, with the parentheses, `fade` gets **called** and the return value is passed to `setTimeout`. Instead, you want to pass the function itself so it can be called later.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I'm also amazed at how quickly I get a response here. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The essential way to program in jQuery is to enclose all DOM accessing code in the $(document).ready() event handler. Redo your javascript as follows:

```
var i = 0;
var count;

function fade() {
    if (i < count-1) {
        $('ul li:nth-child('+(count-i)+')').fadeOut(300);
            i++;
        } else {
            $('ul li:nth-child('+count+')').fadeIn(300, function(){$('ul li').show();});    
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    count = $('ul li').size();
    $('button').click(function() {
        setInterval('fade()', 1000);
    });
} );
```

Note that i, count and fade are declared outside $(document).ready, because their scope is global. This is the key, because the your setInterval handler needs them available globally.

One of the big advantages of jQuery is that no matter where you put your code, you are guaranteed that it will execute just when it should. Code inside $(document).ready won't execute until your entire DOM tree is loaded, thus ensuring all elements you refer are available when accessed.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your browser's JavaScript console, it'll tell you what the exact issue is:

```
fade is not defined
setInterval('fade()', 1000);
```

Try this instead:

```
    $(function() {
        var i = 0;
        var count = $('ul li').size();      


        $('button').click(function() {
            setInterval(function(){
                if (i < count-1) {
                $('ul li:nth-child('+(count-i)+')').fadeOut(300);
                    i++;
                } else {
                    $('ul li:nth-child('+count+')').fadeIn(300, function(){$('ul li').show();});    
                    i = 0;
                }
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
```

Using strings in `setInterval` is difficult to get right.

Comment: Thanks, I did think of putting everything inside an anonymous function, but it didn't seem "neat". Is this considered good practice? What's the advantage?

Comment: @Hanz: Anonymous functions are handy when you have small snippets that won't be run anywhere else. I can't really tell you whether it's good practice is general terms. Whatever, the key point is using the function itself as argument rather than a string to be eval()'d (and, course, defining it in the appropriate scope, as the accepted as @Box9 points out).